# how can I define this and call to use it?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to define this sending message function. But there is something wrong..

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def send_msg(msg):
    async with websockets.client.Connect(url) as websocket:
        print("Connected to WebSocket!")

        await websocket.send(msg)
send_msg('hi')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(send_msg())
loop.run_until_complete(task)

TypeError: send_msg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: What about `task = loop.create_task(send_msg())` ? Shouldn't it contain a `msg` argument?

Comment: task = loop.create_task(send_msg(msg))
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined

this is what i get after changing it

Comment: You need to pass there a string, for instance `task = loop.create_task(send_msg("hey!"))`

Comment: omg you're right! but then how can I use it after import this in another one? do i need to keep using the long last 2 lines?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "after import this in other one"?

Comment: i'm trying to import this function to another ~~~.py file so that i can use this function simply ..? like test01.send_msg('hello')

Comment: ahh, i see. you could simply define a function for that. Should I post it in the answer for you?

Comment: If you're not busy at all, yes! please! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a simple function that you could use later, you can define something like this:

```
async def send(msg):
    async with websockets.client.Connect(url) as websocket:
        print("Connected to Spoon WebSocket!")

        await websocket.send(msg)


def send_msg(msg):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(send(msg))
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

THen you just need to import your `.py` file and run `test01.send_msg('hello')`

Comment: Thank you so much sir! you're the best!!

Comment: glad it helped :)